# Android simple layout of 2 views

Tags: android, android-layout

Can't understand how to implement simple thing.
I need layout of 2 views with next behaviour:

button should be to right of text when text is short
[image]

when text is long it ellipsizes and button always visible and full-width 
[image]

now I get that button is going out of screen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using `ConstraintLayout`. Here's a template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HELLO WORLD"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/text"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The initial setup is:

- Create a horizontal chain including the text and the button
- Set the chain style to "packed" so that there's no space between the views
- Set the horizontal bias to 0 so that the packed views hug to the left

The magic comes with the `TextView`'s width and the `app:layout_constraintWidth_default` attribute. By setting the width to 0dp and the "default width" to wrap, we're telling Android to give the view as much space as it needs to hold its contents *as long as it fits the constraints*. When the text is really long, the constraints will keep it from pushing the button off the right side of the screen.

[image]

[image]